# clustering timestamp with timezone from twitter data

Tags: timestamp, cluster-analysis

I have a postgres database with tweets downloaded and I use a timestamp with timezone column to store the current_timestamp. So that I want to do is to cluster my tweets like this great guy did

> https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11567/spatial-clustering-with-postgis

but instead of geo-clustering I want to make time-clustering. I mean I want to cluster my tweets into groups by the current_timestamp column.
For example I have 10 tweets:

```
 time                                   |       text                   |    tweet_id
2013-07-29 11:17:08.153+03              | some text                    | 12345600bsa9
2013-07-29 11:19:08.153+03              | some text also               | ang698f4s8s4
..
2013-07-29 16:41:00.968+03              | hello                        | 6546448965445
2013-07-29 16:43:00.968+03              | world                        | w9087ol0930j3
```

So with these 4 tweets I want to make two clusters (cluster by checking hour distance) one cluster for the 11:.. hour and one for 16:.. hour. Of course I want to extend this to day cluster, month cluster etc..
Any assistance guys?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Sort the data.

Define a temporal threshold, e.g. 1 hour. If the gap to the previous time is larger than this, split into two clusters.

Time is 1-dimensional; this is not really cluster analysis. One dimensional data can be sorted, and processed as a series; which is MUCH easier.

Comment: Yes that's sounds good but if I want to manage multiple clusters? Suppose that I have 1000 rows with many different timestamps, I want to cluster these rows to a logical number of clusters eg 50 or 100 depends on clustering type (hour, day, month, minute etc)..

Comment: I try to make it with array_agg function, here is my code `SELECT
    text, array_agg(date_part('hour',time)) AS hours,
    count(text) as count
    FROM tweet
    group by text` But I didn't get the correct result (something like -1row- {11,11,11,11,11...} )